# Numerical Solution of difference equation

Tags: reference-request, numerical-methods, recurrence-relations

I am trying to solve a nonlinear difference equation of the form:

$x_{i+1} = f(x_i, x_{i-1})$

for $i = 0,\ldots,N-1$ with given boundary conditions $x_0 = a$ and $x_N = g(x_{N-1})$ where $f$ and $g$ are some arbitrary functions. What sort of numerical methods are available which I could use? I am not very familiar with recurrences and have tried searching for books on numerical methods for difference equations. If anyone could recommend any methods or books that could help me find a numerical solution to this problem I would be very grateful.

Comment: Please clarify the problem. Are you trying to determine $x_1$ to $x_N$? If the difference equation holds for $i=0,...,N$, there must be an $x_{N+1}$. Does $x_N$ satisfy the boundary condition with $g$ as well as the difference equation with $f$?

Comment: Yes we are trying to compute $x_1$ to $x_N$. Thanks for pointing out the mistake in my original question (now corrected). $x_N$ should satisfy the boundary condition.

Comment: @covertbob Thanks for clarification. Still, it seems $x_N$ satisfies both $x_N=f(x_{N-1},x_{N-2})$ and $x_N=g(x_{N-1})$.

Comment: Yes. That's correct.

Comment: Does $f$ have any special structure, or is it a generic unknown function?

Comment: The following iterative technique that should work for well-behaved functions but may not be very efficient. Start with a guess: $x_2=t$, use $f$ repeatedly to determine $x_3(t),...x_{N}(t)$. Calculate $d(t)=g(x_{N-1}(t))-x_{N}(t)$. You want to find $t$ such that $d(t)=0$. Start with good guesses $t_1$ and $t_2$ and iterate. For example, $t_{k+1}=t_k-d(t_k)\times (t_k-t_{k-1})/(d(t_k)-d(t_{k-1}))$. You can use any numerical equation solving technique that doesn't require derivatives.

Answer (score 0):

In general case (for functions $f$ and $g$ in arbitrary form) you can try [shooting method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shooting_method). The elementary algorithm is following:

1. Let us choose approximation $a=x_1$. For this approximation you can calculate $x_N$, denote its value as $F(a)$.
2. Using constructed function $F$ solve numerically the equation $F(a)-x_N=0$ by any appropriate method, for example bisection method or more effective [golden section method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_section_search). In the latter case you find the minimum of function $G(a)=(F(a)-x_N)^2$, which equals $0$ in the solution.

Comment: Would you know any good books which describe the method?

Comment: I found good and short description of this method in Russian book "Numerical Methods for Theoretical Physicists, part 2" by Il'ina V.A and Silaev P.K. But I do not sure it can be found in English.

Comment: There is also less effective "relaxation" method, based on reduction of recurrence relation to the system of linear equations of size 2N.

Comment: The problem you may face, is that solution is not continuous by parameter. In this case this method will fail.